# curvature of vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature

On Well's book, the curvature associated with a bundle is defined as follow:

[image]

But I can't see the geometric meaning and the relation with Gauss and sectional curvature, can somebody help to illustrate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form#Example:_the_Levi-Civita_connection is probably what you want.

Comment: You should start by reading about classical surface theory done with moving frames (i.e., differential forms). You can read a brief section on this in my own differential geometry notes (linked in my profile), but for something a bit more comprehensive, look at Clelland's new book *From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames* or at texts like Chern/Chen/Lam or Spivak, among many others.